# Нужно сформировать очередь, содержащую целые числа и упорядочить их по возрастанию. В процессе упорядочивания элементы очереди перемещаться не должны

Tags: c++, сортировка, очередь

Нужно сформировать очередь, содержащую целые числа и упорядочить их по возрастанию. В процессе упорядочивания элементы очереди перемещаться не должны
Нашёл код, который находит максимальный элемент очереди и переносит его в начало. Но ни как не могу разобраться, что надо изменить, чтобы вся очередь сортировалась.
Вот код:

```
     #include"stdafx.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <conio.h>
        using namespace std;

struct qitem {
    struct qitem *next, *prev;
    int data;
};

struct queue {
    struct qitem *first, *last;
};

struct qitem *add_head(struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
    if (e) {
        e->prev = 0;
        if (e->next = q->first)
            q->first->prev = e;
        else
            q->last = e;
        q->first = e;
    }
    return e;
}

struct qitem  *add_tail(struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
    if (e) {
        e->next = 0;
        if (e->prev = q->last)
            q->last->next = e;
        else
            q->first = e;
        q->last = e;
    }
    return e;
}

struct qitem *remove(struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
    if (e) {
        if (e->next)
            e->next->prev = e->prev;
        else
            q->last = e->prev;
        if (e->prev)
            e->prev->next = e->next;
        else
            q->first = e->next;
    }
    return e;
}

struct qitem *find_max(struct queue *q) {
    struct qitem *cur = q->first, *pmax = cur;
    while (cur) {
        if (cur->data < pmax->data)
            pmax = cur;
        cout <<"re "<< cur;
        cur = cur->next;
        }
    return pmax;
}

struct qitem *make_item(int n) {
    struct qitem *p = new struct qitem;

    p->data = n;
    return p;
}

void print_list(struct queue *q) {
    cout << "queue " << q->first << " : " << q->last << '\n';
    for (struct qitem *cur = q->first; cur; cur = cur->next)
        cout << cur->data <<
        " [ " << cur << ": next " << cur->next << " prev " << cur->prev << "]\n";
}

struct queue randlist(int n)
{
    struct queue my_q = { 0, 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        add_tail(&my_q, make_item((rand() % 100) + 1));

    return my_q;
}

int main() {
    int N;

    cout << "Enter N: ";   cin >> N;

    struct queue my_q = randlist(N);
    print_list(&my_q);

    cout << "---- find max and move it to head ----\n";
    add_head(&my_q, remove(&my_q, find_max(&my_q)));
    print_list(&my_q);

    cout << "---- free memory (remove all queue items and delete them) ----\n";
    struct qitem *p;
    int n = 0;
    while (p = remove(&my_q, my_q.first)) {
        delete p;
        n++;
    }
    cout << "remove " << n << " items\n";
    print_list(&my_q);

    if (n == N)
        cout << "OK!\n";
    else
        cout << "FAIL...\n";
    _getch();
    return N != n;

}
```

Comment: Условие не очень понятно - с одной стороны надо упорядочить очередь, с другой стороны не перемещать её элементы.

Comment: Элементы то может и нельзя перемещать, а указатели на него - можно.